# mysql date and datetime problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table called table1.  with id and dt columns.  The dt is of type datetime.

From this, I am trying to extract all id's with a specific date (not given the time, just the date, like 2011-02-11 say)

I could do it as a between the 00:00:00 and midnight of that date, but is their a proper way to do it with mysql and php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, dt 
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(dt) = '2011-02-11'
```

MySQL's got a pretty comprehensive set of Date/Time handling functions, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)