# MySQL date matching error?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains a list of ID's (int) and the date (datetime) that ID was created.

One ID in particular was created:

2010-12-31 09:45:29

When I run the following query, no results are returned:

```
select * from information where creation = '2010-12-31'
```

What gives? I assume this is because of the timestamp (it does not match 2010-12-31 00:00:00) but seems like it should work as a 'date' in general.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973268/mysql-date-and-datetime-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from information where DATE(creation) = '2010-12-31'
```

You said it yourself, `2010-12-31` = `2010-12-31 00:00:00`, which is not equal to `2010-12-31 09:45:29`. You can use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to ensure you are comparing *apples to apples*.

Comment: got it - thanks for the help. I was not aware I needed to explicitly state the date function within the sql call. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not. Try running

```
select * from information where creation LIKE '2010-12-31%';
```

or

```
select * from information where DATE(creation) = '2010-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from information where DATE_FORMAT(creation,'%Y-%m-%d')  = '2010-12-31'
```